# Object reference count in System Verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I would like to know if there is a way to know the number of references(handles) to an object in System Verilog. I can figure put to put a static counter in the new() method for new objects but for reference count SV is closer to Java and has in-built memory management. 
The LRM states that objects are automatically destroyed when the reference count reaches 0 and whenever an object reference is created the reference count is incremented and when reference is assigned to null the count decreases. But how can I at any point of time know how many references are available??

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing in the language spec to allow this.

It is possible that a given vendor's simulator has an vendor-specific way to do this, but it would be outside of the spec.

Answer (score 0):

This is something the tool has to provide since it implements the automatic memory management. Modelsim/Questa has a capacity report that will tell you the peak and current counts of each object. Later versions also can tell you where each reference is.